# Importing CSV matrix of z values to raster with no x y coordinates using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, csv, georeferencing

I have a CSV file of depth values that have no spatial information. I know the "cell size" of the data but not where it should be put in space.

How do I convert this into a data format, such as tif, that I can import to ArcGIS Desktop to georeference as though it is an image?

Comment: [@pythonNovice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/54052/pythonnovice), do you have at least any spatial information or locations of your data, of course besides z-values?

Comment: Could you show us (part of) this file so we can see what the exact format is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use numpy's [genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to create a numpy array and then convert this to a raster using [NumpyArrayToRaster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/numpyarraytoraster-function.htm).

Example:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import arcpy

my_data = genfromtxt(r'C:\folder\depths.csv', delimiter=',') #If you have a header, add skip_header=1
myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(in_array=my_data, x_cell_size=1, y_cell_size=1)
myRaster.save(r'C:\folder\raster.tif')
```

Comment: This has been a very useful answer as I was facing a similar problem with a very odd data supply in CSV format that needed converting to a raster. If anyone else uses this solution I just want to add if you end up with an inverted raster I used `numpy.flipud()` on `my_data` before converting it into a raster. Thanks @BERA!